# Go: append directly to slice found in a map

Tags: go

I wanted to create a map of slices where values are appended to the corresponding slice. However, when trying to append directly to the slice returned by accessing it (see comment below), it would not be stored, so I had to go with the long form access (line below the comment).

Why is it so? I expected the access to the map to return some sort of pointer, so in my mind `mappedAminoAcid == aminoAcidsToCodons[aminoAcid]`; clearly, I'm wrong.

Thanks!

```
aminoAcidsToCodons := map[rune][]string{}
for codon, aminoAcid := range utils.CodonsToAminoAcid {
    mappedAminoAcid, ok := aminoAcidsToCodons[aminoAcid]

    if ok {
        // NOT WORKING: mappedAminoAcid = append(mappedAminoAcid, codon)
        aminoAcidsToCodons[aminoAcid] = append(mappedAminoAcid, codon)
    } else {
        aminoAcidsToCodons[aminoAcid] = []string{codon}
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how Go works. You get back a new slice from the map index operation. Appending to this slice does append to this slice and doesn't do any magic trick like "I stem from a map index operation so let's modify the map and not me."

Comment: That's interesting, I thought slices worked as basically pointers to arrays, so I thought the index action would return the pointers to that array. Thanks!

Comment: @jonathanGB: slices do work like pointers to an array (a slice header contains a length, capacity, and the array pointer), but you want it to work like a pointer to a pointer to an array.

Comment: The slice itself is a plain value with copy semantics. The backing array it is viewing is shared. It _might_ get updated during append or not, depending on the cap.

Comment: Oh, if I understand correctly the underlying array will be updated, but the len, cap and such slice's metadata will not be updated in the original slice because that data is copied during the index access?

Comment: @jonathanGB: yes, but the array pointer is also part of that copy, so if the array needs to be reallocated that will be a different too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`append` returns a new slice if the underlying array has to grow to accomodate the new element. So yes, you have to put the new slice back into the map. This is no different from how strings work, for instance:

```
var x map[string]string
x["a"] = "foo"

y := x["a"]
y = "bar"

// x["a"] is still "foo"
```

Since a `nil` slice is a perfectly fine first argument for append, you can simplify your code to:

```
aminoAcidsToCodons := map[rune][]string{}
for codon, aminoAcid := range utils.CodonsToAminoAcid {
    aminoAcidsToCodons[aminoAcid] = append(aminoAcidsToCodons[aminoAcid], codon)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, well explained!

Comment: **typed** `nil` is fine for first argument, untyped `nil` is not.