# Appending to a slice that is a value in a map

Tags: pointers, go, slice, go-map

I want to append to a slice that is a value of a map, e.g. given m `map[string][]string`:

```
if values, exists := m[key]; exists {
    values = append(values, v)
//  I don't want to call: m[key] = values
} else {
    m[key] = []string{ v }
}
```

That obviously doesn't work, so I tried instead of appending the value as is, to do something like:

```
valuesPtr := &values
*values = append(values, v)
```

But that doesn't work either.  How can I do that?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492318/go-append-directly-to-slice-found-in-a-map

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that.

`append` returns a new slice, since a slice may have to be resized to complete the append. You must update your map to use the newly returned slice, which cannot be done without referencing by key.

Comment: What if I know the maximum possible capacity and I create the slices to be large enough?  Or, is it possible to create a map with values of arrays instead of slices?  Would I be able to use pointers then?

Comment: @isapir, the capacity doesn't matter here. The length of the slice changes when you append a value, making it a different value, even if the underlying array wasn't relocated.

Comment: Should I delete this question?  There are 2 downvotes so unless it is voted up to at least 0 I think I will remove it.  Interestingly there are upvotes for the answer so that seems useful to some (including myself).